# Cepstrum: quefrency scale to frequency scale

Tags: frequency, signal-processing

Can someone please explain to me how to convert a quefrency scale to the corresponding freqncy?

For example consider this:
A voice signal is measured at 50kHz sampling frequency and FFT power spectrum is calculated with a window size of 2048. The frequency bin size would be 24Hz approximately. Now taking inverse fft of this power spectrum will give you 2048 cepstral points,right ? So how do we calculate the quefrency scale for these points? 1/frequency bin size ?

Also, if assume there is a peak at 10th cepstral point. How do we calculate the frequency that this peak corresponds to ?